# viewing the stack when a crash happens

Tags: c, unix, debugging, aix, dbx

i am using AIX OS.here i am facing a problem that when ever the process crashes there is no stack written in the log.it just gives an information of signal11/10/4 has occured.
but no stack is shown.
since the code is an optimized code i am even not able to debud using dbx.gdb is not installed.
could you please suggest how to see the stack trace whenever the program crashes.
might be with any other tool or incase any cheet method to follow to view the actual stack trace?

advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on AIX 5.1:

Use the ulimit command to set the limit for core dumps, before you start the binary (the limit is likely set to 0, which means you're not getting any core dump at all). You will need to do this in the same shell as the process you run. Then you can use the debugger to see the stack in the core. You will need to have debugging symbols in the binary to make much sense out of it, though. Check 'man ulimit' to see how ulimit works. Good luck!